# How to fix " TextInputLaout with TextInputEditText view I can not implement to show next focus Edittext using imeOption and nextFocustDown attribute"

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I used EditText imeOption working well. But when I use TextInputLayout within TextInputEditText 
I saw many resources over and Implement it in my code 
But I cannot get actually result that I wanted.

```
   <!--mobile number input layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_24px"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/grey_text_color"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/base_padding_small">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etMobileNo"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:hint="Mobile No"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingBottom="26dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/grey_text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etPassword"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_text_color"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Password input layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_24px"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleContentDescription=""
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/visibility_toggle_button"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/grey_text_color"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/base_padding_small"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/grey_text_color">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingBottom="26dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/grey_text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_text_color"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I did helping of this reference but did not work. 
**[Android EditText next focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906672/android-edittext-next-focus/27938962)**

without java code how I can use, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/etPassword"
```

instead of:

```
 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etPassword"
 android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Comment: Thanks, You have made my day happy. I was trying to solve this problem. But I cannot. Now Solved this issue perfectly. -

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Happy Coding :)